# Page won't ccroll after dynamically creating HTML with Javascript

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have created a javascript function that dynamically creates an HTML string, however for some reason once the html loads the page will no longer scroll. If I open the Chrome Developer Console it all of a sudden allows the page to scroll. I have checked and I think I have all of the required open and close div tags. Has anyone seen this before.

Does this have something to do with the javascript not being able to finish before the page loads?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

HTML:

```
//Here is where I call the function to dynamically create the html
<div id="memberList">
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        generateMembers();
    });

    </script>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function generateMembers(){

    var doneTask = false;
    var TrebUser = Parse.Object.extend("TrebUser");
    var queryTrebUser = new Parse.Query(TrebUser);

    queryTrebUser.find({
        success: function(results) {
        //Create the member profiles
            var t ="<div class=\"row-fluid\"><div class=\"span12\">";

            for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                //var member = results[i];

                //alert("results length: " + results.length);
                t += "<div class=\"span3\">\
                        <div class=\"met_team_member\">\
                            <div class=\"met_team_member_preview\">\
                                <img src=\"photos/teamMembers/1.jpg\" alt=\"\" />\
                                <div class=\"met_team_member_overlay\">\
                                    <div class=\"met_team_member_skill\"><div style=\"width: 100%\"><span class=\"met_bgcolor_trans met_color2\">Photoshop</span></div></div>\
                                    <div class=\"met_team_member_skill\"><div style=\"width: 100%\"><span class=\"met_bgcolor_trans met_color2\">Illistration</span></div></div>\
                                    <div class=\"met_team_member_skill\"><div style=\"width: 100%\"><span class=\"met_bgcolor_trans met_color2\">Photography</span></div></div>\
                                    <div class=\"met_team_member_skill\"><div style=\"width: 100%\"><span class=\"met_bgcolor_trans met_color2\">HTML</span></div></div>\
                                </div>\
                            </div>\
                            <div class=\"met_team_member_details met_bgcolor3 met_color2\">\
                                <h2 class=\"met_title_stack\">DESIGNER</h2>\
                                <h3 class=\"met_title_stack met_bold_one\">ERKAN DOE</h3>\
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore magna aliqua. </p>\
                            </div>\
                            <div class=\"met_team_member_socials met_bgcolor clearfix\">\
                                <a href=\"http://www.facebook.com/\" target=\"_blank\" class=\"met_color2\"><i class=\"icon-facebook\"></i></a>\
                                <a href=\"http://www.twitter.com/\" target=\"_blank\" class=\"met_color2\"><i class=\"icon-twitter\"></i></a>\
                                <a href=\"http://www.google.com/\" target=\"_blank\" class=\"met_color2\"><i class=\"icon-google-plus\"></i></a>\
                                <a href=\"mailto:info@metcreative.com\" target=\"_blank\" class=\"met_color2\"><i class=\"icon-envelope\"></i></a>\
                            </div>\
                        </div>\
                    </div>";

                if ((i+1) % 4 == 0){
                    t += "</div></div><div class=\"row-fluid\"><div class=\"span12\">";
                }
            }

            t += "</div></div>";
            document.getElementById('memberList').innerHTML = t;

        },

        error: function(results, error) {
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }

    });

}
```

Comment: Why are you calling the function within a `<div>` element?

Comment: I have to admit, that's the only way I thought to do it. Should I call the function elsewhere? Is there a better way to do this? @defaultNINJA

Comment: Following in what @defaultNINJA said, put the js in a separate file, and call the file after all other DOM elements render. Usually before the closing body tag.

Comment: Resolved! I was using a template that used a Smooth-Scroll attribute within the <body> tag. By dynamically creating the html something must have happened that caused this fancy smooth scrolling tool to stop working. Once I removed that attribute from the body tag it worked just fine.